# How to pass contents on double click from one JTable to another JTable in a different frame?

Tags: java, swing, jtable

I am designing a frame like a invoice. Here I have a JTable2 to which i need data from JTable1 when i double click on it which is in a different frame in the same package. How do I get the data ?

```
String sql = "select * from table1 where Bill_No like'"+jTextField2.getText()+"'";
try{
        pst = conn.prepareStatement(sql);
        rs = pst.executeQuery();
        TableModel original = jTable2.getModel();
        DefaultTableModel model = new DefaultTableModel(jTable2.getSelectedRowCount(), original.getColumnCount());
        for (int col = 0; col < original.getColumnCount(); col++) {
        model.addColumn(original.getColumnName(col));
    }
        int[] selectedRows = jTable2.getSelectedRows();
        for (int targetRow = 0; targetRow < selectedRows.length; targetRow++) {
        int row = selectedRows[targetRow];
        int modelRow = jTable1.convertRowIndexToModel(row);
        for (int col = 0; col < original.getColumnCount(); col++) {
        model.setValueAt(original.getValueAt(modelRow, col), targetRow, col);
    }
}

        NewJFrame2 n = new NewJFrame2();
        n.setVisible(true);           
        int i=0; 
        while(rs.next()) {
        Object bno = rs.getString("Bill No");
        Object bamount = rs.getString("Bill Amount");
        Object btds = rs.getString("TDS");
        Object btax = rs.getString("Tax");
        Object bpayable = rs.getString("Payable");      

        jTable1.getModel().setValueAt(bno,i, 0 );
        jTable1.getModel().setValueAt(bamount, i, 1);
        jTable1.getModel().setValueAt(btds, i, 2);
        jTable1.getModel().setValueAt(btax, i, 3);
        jTable1.getModel().setValueAt(bpayable, i, 4);              
        System.out.println(i);
        i++;
        }
    }
    catch(Exception e){
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, e);
    }
```

Comment: You should share what you've tried, some code that we can execute and see what is wrong. 
You should probably use mouse listener on the table to fire the event of changing the selected row content to another table model.

Comment: @ Bepo This is how i can put data from one jtable to another in the same frame ! I am facing problem in sharing it in a jtable in another frame.




     jTable2.setValueAt(jTable1.getValueAt(0, 0).toString(), 0, 0);
    jTable2.setValueAt(jTable1.getValueAt(0, 1).toString(), 0, 1);
    jTable2.setValueAt(jTable1.getValueAt(0, 2).toString(), 0, 2);

Comment: Na, it shouln't make a difference how many frames you have, and to which frame you send the data. As long you have the table modal, you can place it everywhere.

Comment: @MouseEvent you can see my code. what wrong am i doing ? 
i get a  cannot find symbol JTable1 error

Comment: You never created the other jtable (at-least, in your posted code), and I don't see in your code where you add the table to the frame.

Comment: This is frame 1 where i am trying to use table2 of frame2.

Comment: Have a look at [Passing Information to a Method or a Constructor](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/arguments.html) for information about how to pass information between classes

Comment: See [The Use of Multiple JFrames, Good/Bad Practice?](http://stackoverflow.com/q/9554636/418556)  One (or possibly more) of those frames should probably be a `JDialog`.  Then when modal it becomes simpler to update the table in the 'main' frame or dialog.

Answer (score 0):

You should not use setValue, it's better to work with the table model, you will have an extended control.

I made an example, If you have something like:

```
MyTableModel model1 = new MyTableModel();
MyTableModel model2 = new MyTableModel();
JTable table1 = new JTable(model1);
JTable table2 = new JTable(model2);
```

With the table model class:
public class MyTableModel extends AbstractTableModel {

```
    private String[] columnNames = { "Col 1", "Col 2", "Col 3"};
    private Vector<Vector<String>> data;//I am using String because I don't know what you need

    public int getColumnCount() {
      return columnNames.length;
    }

    public Vector<Vector<String>> getData(){
        return data;
    }

    public void setData(Vector<Vector<String>> data){
        this.data=data;
        fireTableDataChanged();
    }

    public int getRowCount() {
      return data.size();
    }

    public String getColumnName(int col) {
      return columnNames[col];
    }

    public Object getValueAt(int row, int col) {
      return data.elementAt(row).elementAt(col);
    }
    public Class getColumnClass(int c) {
      return getValueAt(0, c).getClass();
    }

    public boolean isCellEditable(int row, int col) {
        return false;
    }

    public void setValueAt(Object value, int row, int col) {
        data.elementAt(row).set(col,value.toString());
      fireTableCellUpdated(row, col);
    }

  }
```

Then you can have a mouse listener to the table, that let you modify the content of the table models:

```
table1.addMouseListener(new MouseAdapter() {
            public void mousePressed(MouseEvent me) {
                JTable table =(JTable) me.getSource();
                Point p = me.getPoint();
                int row = table.rowAtPoint(p);
                if (me.getClickCount() == 2) {
                    Vector<Vector<String>> data1=model1.getData();
                    Vector<String> line=data.elementAt(row);
                    //remove from first table
                    data1.remove(row);
                    model1.setData(data);
                    //add it to the second one (at the end)
                    Vector<Vector<String>> data2 = model2.getData();
                    data2.add(line);
                    model2.setData(data2);
                }
            }
        });
```

Comment: Why go to all the extra work of creating a `TableModel` implementation when you've basically implemented a `DefaultTableModel` ... And `Vector`?  It's a little out-of-date